# JSON.parse converting to a string instead of passing into array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Yallo, I am at ends as to why `notes = JSON.parse(notesString)` is converting my array to a string instead of passing my json strings into the array. I tested by checking the `typeof` before and after. I understand why push cannot be used because it's no longer an array. but I don't know the solution.

Code

```
// array to store notes in
var notes = [];

// note JSON object
var note = {
    title: title,
    body: body
};

try {
    // read pre-existing content of notes-data.json file
    var notesString = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');

    // store pre-existing data as the notes array, passing as 
    // JSON
    console.log("notesString: " + typeof notesString)
    console.log("notes before parse: " + typeof notes)

    notes = JSON.parse(notesString)

    console.log("notes after parse:" + typeof notes)
} catch (e) {

}

// add note to notes array
notes.push(note)

// store content of notes array in notes-data.json as a string 
fs.writeFileSync('notes-data.json', JSON.stringify(notes));
```

This is my JSON

```
"[{\"title\":\"herp\",\"body\":\"derp\"},{\"title\":\"herp\"‌​‌​,\"body\":\"derp\"‌​}]‌​"
```

Output

```
notesString: object
notes before parse: object
notes after parse:string
C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Note_App_NodeJS\Note_App_NodeJS\notes.js:32
    notes.push(note)
          ^

TypeError: notes.push is not a function
```

**Resolved**
sorry people I don't know what was going on but I should have validated my output/input first. I don't know why it was formatted in that manner and it's formatted in the correct json format since, when converting to stingify then parsing back. I am using Visual Studio with the Nodejs extension so perhaps that had something to do with it.

Comment: What is `notes-data.json`?

Comment: Having tested this, the only explanation I can come up with is that the JSON file contains a string and not an array. Your [mcve] is lacking the JSON data, which is essential for the understanding of this question.

Comment: an empty .json file I am storing stringified json into

Comment: If it is empty then you should get `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` (although your try/catch would hide that), it shouldn't get as far as logging "notes after parse".

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific at the momment it contains "[{\"title\":\"herp\",\"body\":\"derp\"},{\"title\":\"herp\",\"body\":\"derp\"}]"

Comment: Can you post the output of ``console.log(JSON.stringify(notesString))`` after fs.readFileSync. I think I know the cause.

Comment: Hey @gxminbdd If your .json file is empty nodejs will thrown an error "Unexpected end of JSON input"  JSON.parse will return an object not an array and "notes" is not an array. if you want to check try this  console.log("is notes is an array!" + Array.isArray(notes)); //return false.

Comment: Just remove the outer quotes in your JSON "[{\"title\":\"herp\",\"body\":\"derp\"},{\"title\":\"herp\"‌​,\"body\":\"derp\"}]‌​". That's why it says it is a string.

Comment: @germanfr It will throw an error "unexpected token \" if you remove the outer quotes.

Comment: @sajankumarvijayan that's because your json is invalid. You have to remove all the \ there. Keys and values must be strings.

Comment: @germanfr yes I know, and gxminbdd your .json file should have some data like this [{
 "title": "herp",
 "body": "derp"
}, {
 "title": "herp",
 "body": "derp"
}] then it will work.

Comment: @germanfr it is really useful.So I accepted. It doesn't matter who asked :) Enjoy bro :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a string because of the outer quotes. If you remove those, your JSON is not valid. You must format it according to the JSON rules. All the keys must be strings, and values can be only primitives, like strings, numbers, booleans, arrays or other JSON objects.

Format your JSON like

```
[
    {
        "title": "herp",
        "body":"derp"
    },
    {
        "title":"herp"‌​‌​,
        "body":"derp"‌
    ​}
]‌​
```

Here you can see some examples: http://json.org/example.html

Comment: "Your JSON is not valid" — It is a perfectly valid string.

Comment: Not if he removes the outer quotes. He does not want to have a string.

Answer (score 3):

> sorry I should have been more specific at the momment it contains
>
> ```
> "[{\"title\":\"herp\",\"body\":\"derp\"},{\"title\":\"herp\"‌​,\"body\":\"derp\"}]‌​"
> ```

That is the JSON expression of a string, which is why you get a string when you parse it.

The string happens to contain a nested set of JSON which is the array you are looking for.

Extract that array from the string and put that in the file.

```
[{"title":"herp","body":"derp"},{"title":"herp"‌​,"body":"derp"}]‌​
```