# parse json response to typescript class

Tags: json, typescript

i know there are multiple similar topics, however trying their solutions doesn't give me expected result.

**Input** json string

```
data:"{"message": "{\"type\":\"CONTROL\",\"command\":\"REQUEST_STATUS_ALL\"}"}"
```

**object declaration/parse:**

```
const msg: Message = <Message>JSON.parse(data.data);
```

**output:**

```
{message: "{"type":"CONTROL","command":"REQUEST_STATUS_ALL"}"}
```

-values are not properly assigned, but instead in a text form.

the same object looks like this if it's initialized manually(in TS):

```
Message {type: "CONTROL", status: undefined, command: "REQUEST_STATUS_ALL", body: undefined}
```

What is the correct way to parse that json string into the `Message` object?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.parse converting to a string instead of passing into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196847/json-parse-converting-to-a-string-instead-of-passing-into-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the value for message was improperly encoded as a string.  Calling `JSON.parse` a second time on the message property will get the result you want, though you might want to fix the underlying cause of the improperly encoded data instead.

```
parseMessage(data: string) {
   const msgTemp = JSON.parse(data);
   msgTemp.message = JSON.parse(msgTemp.message);
   return <Message>msgTemp;
}

const msg = parseMessage(data.data);
```